# Java insert bytes to file at given position without overwriting any data

Tags: java, list, insert, filechannel

I have a List backed by (among other things) a FileChannel (of a relatively large file), enabling random reads to objects. The implementations of `get()`, `size()`, and `add()` were fairly straightforward. However, any `remove()` and `set()` calls are delegated to a call to `close()`, where a  correct temporary file is made and then moved to the original path. This takes up to 2*n disk space. I'd like to avoid this by dynamically resizing the underlying file on the fly to enable in place editing.

I have a solution in mind, but I'd like to know if someone could think of a more elegant solution. **I'd like to stress that I don't at all need compilable code. I'd simply like to know if there's a more elegant solution, and if there is, language agnostic theory would work just fine.**

***My proposed solution potentially rewrites the whole file on every `set()`, and `remove()` (if the mutation happens near the beginning of the collection); and that seems inefficient. Is there any way around this, or am I stuck between the proverbial rock of disk space (writing out a temp file) and the hard place of disk usage (potentially rewriting the whole file for every mutation)?***

```
void swap(long srcPos, long destPos, int nBytes) { //enables "bubbling" of bytes. Just like bubblesort. 
    ... //Have this implemented, can share in an edit if needed
}

E remove(int index) {
    //Bubble out the element to the end of file using swap(), then truncate
}

E set(int index, E element) {
    ... //Get element at index, and defines oldSize and NewSize
    if(oldSize == newSize) {
        //Sizes match, no bubbling required.
        //Replace bytes directly.
    } else if(oldSize < newSize) {
        //Old size is less than new size
        //Replace bytes directly, then bubble out difference and truncate
    } else if(oldSize > newSize) {
        //Old size is greater than new size
        //Grow file by difference
        //Bubble in zeros from end of file to position
        //Replace bytes directly
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  You want to have an in-memory data structure backed by a disk file.  Is there a need for things in the disk file to be ordered the same as the list in memory?  With appropriate metadata you could have a disk file managed by its own class that allocated space as needed and was able to defragment itself when required, and completely decouple the in-memory list's order from the on-disk representation.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm doing something similar already to enable O(1) access, but I'd like to persist changes to the list without writing out a correctly mutated temporary file. Also, am I not asking for what I want? I'd like to insert n bytes into i position in a file without overwriting any bytes in the file, and even proposed a terrible solution to said problem.

Comment: The only other solution I can come up with is to pad elements to ensure contiguous size, but the underlying elements can vary dramatically in size; so I'd like to avoid doing that as it could potentially use more disk space than my naive write-changes-to-temporary-file-and-move-back-on-close approach.

Comment: You're asking for what you think you want, I'm suggesting you may want to reconsider a more general solution that does not need to maintain the order on disk, resulting in O(1) behavior with an occasional garbage collection.  A real disk cache would maintain a list of free blocks of space within the file, and when you need to write a new object it would find the first block large enough to contain the data.  If none were available it would write to the end of the file.  Objects would be moved only at garbage collection time.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I think I see. You're suggesting I look into blocks on the hdd instead of files? Thanks! You should make that a short answer so I can give you some rep :D

Comment: @JimGarrison, would your suggestion remain the same if the elements potentially numbered into the millions and I needed to sort the elements every run for a binary search?

Comment: Be aware that going that route can be rather complex depending on your requirements. You may want to look at existing open-source disk caching solutions.  Start with researching "java disk backed collection".  There's a TON of material on the web.  Once you understand the basic concepts you can decide if you want to use an O/S product, adapt someone else's code or roll your own.

Comment: Thanks, @JimGarrison, you're the bomb!

Answer (score 0):

I think something similar can be achieved using [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)

You can check the documentation and some examples.
The steps would be something like

1. Open the file in rw mode (Read and Write)
2. Use the seek method to get into the file position you will start writting
3. Write the bytes
4. Don't forget to close your opened resources !

Comment: I switched from a `RandomAccessFile` to a `FileChannel` for performance reasons. Furthermore, this does not insert bytes, this overwrites them.